# Sphinx different results with MATCH

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

So, I have a situation where I want both no MATCH and MATCH all items to get me the same results, but have been getting inconsistent results.

These are the current types in the DB:

```
mysql> select the_type from data GROUP BY the_type;
+-----------------+
| the_type        |
+-----------------+
| type1           |
| type2           |
+-----------------+
```

If I don't specify any criteria:

```
mysql> select COUNT(*) as num from data;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
| 2131 |
+------+
```

With a MATCH for all types:

```
mysql> select COUNT(*) as num from data WHERE MATCH('(@the_type type1|type2)');
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  430 |
+------+
```

Is it me or should both queries return the same exact count?

Edit:

After some digging I found out that one of my "types" had hyphen in it.

So something like:

```
MATCH('(@the_type type1|type2)')
```

will result in "type1" OR "type2", but something like:

```
MATCH('(@the_type type1|type-two)')
```

will be "type1" OR "type" AND "two".

Now I tried converting the type to an INT field and was trying to do:

```
mysql> select COUNT(*) as num from data WHERE type = 1 OR type = 2;
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected OR, expecting $end near 'OR type = 2'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you read the warning about max_matches here: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#clustering

Comment: Yes, I run my production query with: OPTION max_matches = 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'OR' in sphinx'es WHERE clause.

1. But can do `WHERE type IN (1,2);`
2. If really want to use OR, can put it in the SELECT part, (see also the IF function)

   ```
   select COUNT(*) as num, (type = 1 OR type = 2) AS filter from data WHERE filter =1;
   ```
3. could also try `MATCH('(@the_type type1|"type-two")')` To keep the hyphenated (or multiple word) version together.